# connect with jmx secured by username/password

Tags: clojure, jmx

Using clojure.java.jmx I'm trying to connect with JMX server protected with username/password:

```
(jmx/with-connection {:host "my.server", :port 50001 :environment {"jmx.remote.credentials" ["username" "password"]}} (jmx/mbean "java.lang:type=OperatingSystem"))
```

But what I get is:

```
ClassNotFoundException clojure.lang.PersistentVector (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)  sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass (LoaderHandler.java:396)
```

Aby thoughts what's happened here?

Comment: maybe [thia answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6348219/642340) can help

Comment: Thanks, I went through this one as well. Unfortunately I can't really figure out what the java.rmi.server.codebase should point to in case of plain ring-based app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

aghh... sorry guys. I just found a reason. as a clojure newbe I tried to send environment parameters as clojure Vector instead of java array of Strings. Following is the snippet which solves my problem:

```
(jmx/with-connection {:host "my.server", :port 50001 :environment {"jmx.remote.credentials" (into-array String ["username" "password"])}} (jmx/mbean "java.lang:type=OperatingSystem"))
```