# Spring boot remote Websphere EJB call

Tags: spring, spring-boot, ejb, websphere

I have Websphere thin client jars in my classpath and a sample spring boot application. I am unable to make remote ejb call because it is throwing corab exception. I am using oracle jdk1.8 to make websphere ejb call

```
    09:50:28.505 com.ibm.rmi.corba.PluginRegistry instantiatePlugins:119 P=428317:O=0:CT ORBRas[default]  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.ws.wlm.client.WLMClient (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
        at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:396)
        at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:186)
        at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader$2.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:637)
        at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:219)
        at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:152)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.util.JDKBridge.loadClassM(JDKBridge.java:189)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.util.JDKBridge.loadClass(JDKBridge.java:86)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.javax.rmi.CORBA.Util.loadClass(Util.java:602)
        at javax.rmi.CORBA.Util.loadClass(Util.java:265)
        at com.ibm.rmi.corba.PluginRegistry.instantiatePlugins(PluginRegistry.java:116)
        at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ORB.instantiatePlugins(ORB.java:1518)
        at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ORB.orbParameters(ORB.java:1423)
        at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ORB.set_parameters(ORB.java:1349)
        at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ORB.set_parameters(ORB.java:1697)
        at org.omg.CORBA.ORB.init(ORB.java:353)
        at com.ibm.ws.orb.GlobalORBFactory.init(GlobalORBFactory.java:92)
        at com.ibm.ejs.oa.EJSORBImpl.initializeORB(EJSORBImpl.java:169)
        at com.ibm.ejs.oa.EJSClientORBImpl.<init>(EJSClientORBImpl.java:64)
        at com.ibm.ejs.oa.EJSClientORBImpl.<init>(EJSClientORBImpl.java:44)
        at com.ibm.ejs.oa.EJSORB.init(EJSORB.java:85)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.Helpers.getOrb(Helpers.java:505)
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getInitialContextInternal(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:466)
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.getContext(WsnInitCtx.java:128)
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.getContextIfNull(WsnInitCtx.java:765)
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:164)
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:179)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
        at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate$1.doInContext(JndiTemplate.java:155)
        at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:87)
        at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:152)
        at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:179)
        at org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorSupport.lookup(JndiLocatorSupport.java:104)
        at org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorDelegate.lookup(JndiLoc
```

The above log shows the corba errors generated by ibm jar files.

Answer (score 0):

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.ws.wlm.client.WLMClient

Looks like this is the class you're missing.

You'll need to add the **com.ibm.ws.wlm.jar** to your class path.

Comment: I verified and the required jar files are in the classpath

Comment: Take a look at the answers here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322107/java-no-security-manager-rmi-class-loader-disabled
It's likely you have access to com.ibm.ws.wlm.jar on one side of the Server/Client equation, but not the other.