# Uploading Large Files to JackRabbit Repository Using API

Tags: java, jackrabbit, jackrabbit-oak

We configured JackRabbit repository for storing the files and other file manipulation. Here we are trying to upload large files to the `JackRabbit Repository` using `CreateDocumentFromFilePath API`. It is throwing below error message `"com.rovicorp.jackrabbit.exception.JackrabbitException: JE_00002/nShort Message:::Exception from Jackrabbit Repository"`.

We tried to upload the file less than `30MB` and it is working fine. But if we go more than that, it is throwing an error message.

We further debugged on this issue and we see that the below error message:

```
"Caused by: org.apache.jackrabbit.rmi.client.RemoteRepositoryException:
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: Error unmarshaling return; nested exception is:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
org.apache.jackrabbit.core.data.DataStoreException (no security manager: RMI
class loader disabled)"
```

We read in the internet and need to configure `Repository.xml` file for maximum size of the uploaded file. We are not able to figure it out how to configure it in the `Repository.xml`. Attached the error message of the screen shot.

[image]

We want to upload large files to the 'JackRabbit Repository' using `CreateDocumentFromFilePath API`.

Can you help us to fix this issue?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: which Servlet container you use?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: no security manager: RMI class loader disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322107/java-no-security-manager-rmi-class-loader-disabled)

Comment: Please post exception stacktraces as text, not as screenshots.

Comment: We are using Tomee and we deployed as war file in Tomee

Answer (score 0):

Let's check the Jackrabbit's documentation about [Database Data Store](https://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/DataStore), and see:

> When adding a binary object, Jackrabbit checks the size of it. When it is larger than `minRecordLength`(default 100 bytes), it is added to the data store, otherwise it is kept in-memory. This is done very early (possible when calling `Property.setValue(stream)`). Only the unique data identifier is stored in the persistence manager (except for in-memory objects, where the data is stored). When updating a value, the old value is kept there (potentially becoming garbage) an the new value is added. There is no update operation.
>
> The current implementation still stores temporary files in some situations, for example in the `RMI client`. Those cases will be changed to use the data store directly where it makes sense.

After looking at your exception: `DataStoreException (no security manager: RMI
class loader disabled)`, we come to the idea that, your client just don't have permission for RMI server. And this questions have already been answered here: [Java: no security manager: RMI class loader disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322107/java-no-security-manager-rmi-class-loader-disabled)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. I have checked the link what you have provided. But we don't see options how to configure that permission in RMI.

Comment: how to configure permission in RMI, I provided in the last sentence, the link to another question in stackoverflow

Comment: by the way, it is another question. 2 questions - 2 question posts